# Can't connect to new Google Cloud SQL instance created via JDBC tutorial

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to Google Cloud SQL for MySQL from Apps Script using JDBC. I've followed the [Cloud SQL Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc), created the `mysql-instance` mentioned, cleared "Enable deletion protection ", copied the generated password into the code snippet below copied from the [Apps Script JDBC sample GitHub repo](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples/blob/master/service/jdbc.gs), but I keep getting this useless error, no matter what I put in the connection name:

> Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password

Here's the full code:

```js
const connectionName = 'myproj-906811:us-central1:mysql-instance';
const rootPwd = '...';

const root = 'root';
const instanceUrl = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + connectionName;


/**
 * Create a new database within a Cloud SQL instance.
 */
function createDatabase() {
  try {
    const conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(instanceUrl, root, rootPwd);
    conn.createStatement().execute('CREATE DATABASE foo');
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO(developer) - Handle exception from the API
    console.log('Failed with an error', err);
  }
}
```

I got the connection name from here:

[image: SQL instance Overview page]

The error doesn't say what exactly is incorrect, but I've copy/pasted the password and the connection name, so what is the problem?